# Get stdout from NPM Script into a variable

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, sass, npm-scripts

I have this node script that parse a .YAML and output a field named **version**

```
node node/getAssetsVersion.js
=> "2.1.2"
```

I'm trying to get that **stdout** into a varible and use it in a NPM Script

This is what I'm trying to do in my **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "cross-env VERSION=\"$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js)\" \"node-sass --include-path scss src/main.scss dist/$VERSION/main.css\""
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
VERSION=\"$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js)\"
```

you may need to use:

```
VERSION=\"$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js | cut -d'\"' -f2)\"
```

if the output of your program is this as you wrote in the question:

```
=> "2.1.2"
```

If it's just this:

```
"2.1.2"
```

then the above will still work but you can use a simpler command:

```
VERSION=$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js)
```

with no quotes.

But in the later part the `$VERSION` will likely not get substituted as you expect.

Since you tagged you question with `bash` I would recommend writing a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js | cut -d'\"' -f2)
node-sass --include-path scss src/main.scss dist/$VERSION/main.css
```

or:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=$(node node/getAssetsVersion.js)
node-sass --include-path scss src/main.scss dist/$VERSION/main.css
```

depending on what is the output of getAssetsVersion.js and put this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "bash your-bash-script-name"
}
```

I would avoid any quotes that are escaped more than once.